# I need assistance with cleaning up my code

Tags: python

How do you insert `"name"` into: `print("Hello " + name + "!")` without concatenation?
This is how my code looks like:

```
name = raw_input("Please insert name: ")
print("Hello " + name + "!")
```

I wish it could look more like this:
`print(Hello +name+ !")`

EDIT: Since I can't delete this I want to apologize for the ridiculous question. I don't know what I was thinking at the time.

Comment: You're asking how to concatenate without concatenation. Any answer you get is unlikely to be very pythonic, or will look even more unsual. The way you have it currently is 'clean'.

Comment: I disagree, chopped up code isn't very good. Just based off how it looks, not very nice.

Comment: As stated below in an answer, use `"Hello %s!" % name` if you really don't like string concatenation. IMO, the aesthetic of the code doesn't REALLY matter in a trivial operation like this.

Comment: @JohnErmingham, concatenation of strings in python is simply achieved by using the add ("+") operator. You can just add string variables (like `name` in your code) or literals (expressions you just add like `"Hello"` or `"!"`). If you just want to print something, there are other alternatives in python like: `print("Hello %s!" % name)` or `print("Hello {}!".format(name))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
name = raw_input("Please insert name:")
print("Hello", name, "!")
```

or

Using string formatting:

```
name = raw_input("Please insert name:")
print("Hello %s!" % name)
```

Comment: Assuming OP is using Python 3, that is not the preferred method of string formatting (use `.format()` or f-strings instead).

Comment: Nope, I'm using python 2.7 that's why I'm using "raw_input" instead of just input.

Comment: I assumed he was using Python 2 since he used raw_input which is not used in Python 3. However, if he is using Python 3, then you are totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just dont like using the +, I believe you can do it like this

```
print("Hello {}!".format(name))
```